# jQuery validation plugin - validate empty field on blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a form on my website. It works alright on fields that require a certain number of characters or a specific format(such as email), but it does not immediately show an error if someone focuses a required input and then tabs out of it without entering anything. What I would like it to do is if someone focuses a required input and then moves on to another field(blur) without entering anything, it will immediately display the error. Is this possible?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
      fname: 'required',
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      fname: 'Please enter your first name',
      msgemail: 'Please enter a valid email address'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
  margin-top:20px;
}

label.error {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="contact">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" /> <!-- This should show error if left empty on blur -->
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onfocusout` event when you call the constructor.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contact').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { 
        $(element).valid(); 
    },
    rules: {
      fname: 'required',
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      fname: 'Please enter your first name',
      msgemail: 'Please enter a valid email address'
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
  margin-top:20px;
}

label.error {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="contact">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" /> <!-- This should show error if left empty on blur -->
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
</form>
```